# Parsing an inconsistent field in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a file with different field formats on some lines.  Some different formats I have found so far are:

```
NAME
NAME (Alternate name)
NAME [Alternate name a]/[Alternate name b]
```

I can use regexes to match each different format.  In a language I used to use, I dealt with this problem by doing something that in Python I would expect to look like this:

```
if m = re.search('asd',line):
    a = m.group(1)
    b = m.group(2)
elif m = re.search('qwe',line):
    a = m.group(1)
    b = m.group(2)
```

...which is a syntax error.

I saw the := was out in Python 3.8, but I am trapped at 3.6.  Maybe that will let me do this.  It doesn't matter, though, because I need to solve the problem using 3.6.

How do I cleanly test a line against multiple regexes and use the match results in Python 3.6?